# How can I get data from Web Api With Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to get Mongo database with asp.net web api and take web api data with Angular. I created emprecord.service.ts,employee.component.html, employee.component.ts. But data doesn't appear on the employee page even though it showing on the web api. What may cause this problem? Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance.

My emprecord.service.ts.

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { Observable } from "rxjs";  
import {HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";  
import { Employee } from "../app/employee"; 
 
@Injectable({  
  providedIn: 'root'  
})  
export class EmprecordService {  
   Url="http://localhost:53202/api";  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }  
  
   GetEmployeeRecord():Observable<Employee[]>  
   {  
     debugger;  
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.Url+"/GetDataEmp/GetAllEmployee")  
   }  
}
```

My employee.component.html.

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom:20px;padding-top:20px;">  
    <div class="row">  
      <div class="col-sm-12 btn btn-success">  
        Employee's Information
      </div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;padding-top:20px;">  
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-sm-6">  
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" routerLink="/addemployee">  
            Add New Employee  
          </button>  
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
  <div class="container" style="padding-top:20px;">  
    <table class="table table-striped">  
      <thead class="thead-dark">  
        <th>Name</th>  
        <th>Department</th>  
        <th>Address</th>  
        <th>City</th>  
        <th>Country</th>  
        <th>Action</th>  
      </thead>  
      <tbody>  
        <tr *ngFor="let e of emp">  
        
          <td>{{e.name}}</td>  
          <td>{{e.department}}</td>  
          <td>{{e.address}}</td>  
          <td>{{e.city}}</td>  
          <td>{{e.country}}</td>  
          <td>  
            <div class="btn-group">  
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" (click)="EmployeeEdit(e.Id)">Edit</button>  
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-1" (click)="Deleteemployee(e.Id)">Delete</button>  
            </div>  
          </td>  
        </tr>  
      </tbody>  
    </table> 
  </div>
```

My employee.component.ts.

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { Employee } from "../employee";  
import { EmprecordService } from "../emprecord.service";  
import { Observable } from "rxjs";  
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-employee',  
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']  
})  
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {  
  private emp: Observable<Employee[]>;  
  massage:String;  
  dataSaved=false;  
  constructor(private router: Router,private emprecordService:EmprecordService) { }  
   Loademployee()  
   {  
    debugger;  
    this.emp = this.emprecordService.GetEmployeeRecord(); 
    console.log(this.emp);       
    debugger;       
   }  
  }  
  ngOnInit() {  
    localStorage.clear();
    this.Loademployee();      
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subscribe to the observable to initialize the request and consume the results. So instead of

```
    this.emp = this.emprecordService.GetEmployeeRecord();
```

you should

```
    this.emprecordService.GetEmployeeRecord().subscribe(result => this.emp = result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe.

```
this.emprecordService.GetEmployeeRecord()
    .subscribe(e => this.emp = e);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.http.get` returns an observable. You need to subscribe to this observable in order to get the data. I suggest you read the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data).

Try this

```
this.emprecordService.GetEmployeeRecord().subscribe(data => {
  this.emp = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { Employee } from "../employee";  
import { EmprecordService } from "../emprecord.service";  
import { Observable } from "rxjs";  
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-employee',  
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']  
})  
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {  
  private emp: Observable<Employee[]>;  
  massage:String;  
  dataSaved=false;  
  constructor(private router: Router,private emprecordService:EmprecordService) { }  
   Loademployee()  
   {  
    debugger;  
    this.emp = this.emprecordService.GetEmployeeRecord().subscribe(result => this.emp = result); 
    console.log(this.emp);       
    debugger;       
   }  
  }  
  ngOnInit() {  
    localStorage.clear();
    this.Loademployee();      
  }   
}
```